# What is the rationale for not specifying the job title, only the business unit in the signature?

Tags: email, signatures

During the last month I have noticed that virtually most of company employees are not specifying the job title within their signatures. A typical signature would look like the following:

```
Thanks formula
Name
Company name
Business unit (no job title). E.g. Data Warehouse
Logo
Contact information
```

So, one receiving such an e-mail would not instantly know if the person is the manager or some software developer (unless checking Outlook metadata). For me this seems rather strange as some business units include dozens of persons and may create confusion among contacts outside the organization.

I asked a few colleagues about this and they do not have an explanation. They have just imitated the signature from someone else without questioning about this.

Our HR is periodically sending some e-mails about signatures, but these only include reminders for the general information and the logo to use.

**Question:** What is the rationale for not specifying the job title, only the business unit in the signature?

Comment: Maybe they don't have well-established roles? How old is the company, and how many people are in it?

Comment: @Kozaky - It is a big company: only the branch I am working for has more than 700 people working in dozens of verticals, departments etc. There are many clear roles such as programmers, architects, people managers, scrum masters, product owners etc.

Comment: Much like any rationale for any decision, I expect the answer to vary depending on the person.  With that said, I could share MY RATIONALE as I do not specify my job title in my signature, but I'm not sure that would be helpful for future visitors to this page.

Comment: @Lumberjack - I thought that this might be related to some standard organizational culture feature. The organization has recently transitioned to being Agile, maybe it is related to this somehow.

Comment: Perhaps location(country) is important? Some places just don't view titles as important.

Comment: @Niall - main office is located within Central Europe and our branch within an Eastern European country (within EU). I would say that seniority is not that important, but some title are de facto important (e.g. there is a big difference when talking to a manager vs. talking to a developer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend by company and culture (and company culture), so the following answer is for my specific company culture.

On my team, we have various job titles: Programmer/Analyst I, Programmer/Analyst II, Sr Programmer Analyst, Business Analyst.  But we're all on one team.  We work together, and what is important is what we do and how we do it.  We mostly don't even think about our titles.  What is important is our name and our team.  No one includes titles in email signatures.

If titles are important, or if a company wants a standard signature block that includes them, then they will be included.  If what you are doing and what team you are on is more important, or if standards are not required, then people will include what they think is important, and nothing more.

Comment: +1. Yes, it makes perfect sense not specify seniority, but there is a great difference between a people manager (which in our case might have very little technical knowledge) and some software developer, especially when e-mails are going outside the team. If I receive an e-mail from a random person, my answer might vary depending on the job title (e.g. less tech gibberish for managers). Anyway I have a deep feeling that this also applies in my company. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For most of my work emails, I don't include a formal signature at all. I only use a signature if I'm sending an email to someone I don't regularly work with who might not remember me. Even then, I have different signatures depending on whether my email is staying internal or going external, but none of them specify my job title. Here's an example:

> David K
> ABC Division
> ACME Co.
> 555-555-5555

I don't list my actual job title, because I try to avoid a super long signature, and it doesn't really add any useful information. My job title is "Electronics Engineer." Aside from being extremely vague, it isn't very accurate either. I do include my Division, which should give an idea of what I work on, but there are still two section breakdowns below that which I don't call out, mainly because they aren't very useful.

The one time I do use a title is for official communications related to a role I have. I am in charge of maintaining of one of our lab spaces, so anytime I am emailing in regard to that lab I include "Lab 5 Custodian" in my signature. This indicates to someone who might not know me why I am the person contacting them and what authority I have in the situation. I would expect managers and other leads to include their title in emails in the same sense - when it is relevant to the email they are sending.

Comment: So, the standard signature is not including job title, but it might change depending on recipients. That's a good idea.

Comment: @Alexei And I just added to my answer, most of the time I don't have a signature at all. It's really only if I think someone might not know me.